# Pairs of distances squared - numpy - python

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a text (see [K-nearest neighors example](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.08-sorting.html#Example:-k-Nearest-Neighbors))

which gives this line of code

```
   dist_sq = np.sum((X[:,np.newaxis,:] - X[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)
```

Here X is a numpy 10x2 array which represents 10 points in the 2D plane.
It was initialized like this:

`X = np.random.rand(10, 2)`

OK... The text claims this line computes the pairs of squared distances between the points.
I have no idea why this works and if it works. I tried understanding it but I just can't. I personally try to avoid such cryptic code. This is just not human IMHO. The text explains this code in some details but it seems I don't get that explanation either.

Also, `axis=-1` adds up to the confusion.

Could someone decrypt this line of code?

Also, what is the point of saying e.g. `X[:,np.newaxis,:]`, `X[np.newaxis,:,:]`?

Isn't `X[:,np.newaxis]`, `X[np.newaxis,:]` enough? Isn't it doing the same?!

Also, from combinatorics, the squared distances count should be `10*9/2` or `10*10/2` (if we include equal points which have distance 0), but this `dist_sq` is a 10x10x2 array. So this also adds up to the confusion?! Why 200 elements?!

Comment: `X[np.newaxis]` is the same as `X[np.newaxis,:]` and `X[np.newaxis,:,:]`

Comment: numpy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html): tile arrays to the desired shape when necessary.

Comment: The extra `:` is not strictly necessary, but in m y opinion it improves the self-documentation by letting you know the result will have 3 axes.

Comment: The size is 200 because it includes each point subtracted from itself.  That doesn't impact your sum, since the difference is 0.

Comment: I totally agree that we should "avoid such cryptic code. This is just not human IMHO." I found the book should at least build some ladders towards such an obscured coding block...

Answer (score 2):

You could analysis different parts of your code simply.

Check `X` shape: `X.shape=(10, 2)` .What does `X[np.newaxis,:,:]` do in this command?
It adds new dimension as first dimension of X and convert to `(1, 10, 2)` dimension numpy array. Similarly `X[:,np.newaxis,:]` creats `(10, 1, 2)` numpy array.

`(X[:,np.newaxis,:] - X[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2` has `(10, 10, 2)` dimension.

How about: `dist_sq = np.sum((X[:,np.newaxis,:] - X[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)`. It calculates euclidean distance between each pair of points in `X`

for example:

```
Y =
array([[0.79410882, 0.38156374],
           [0.93574123, 0.6510161 ]])
```

Results of `(Y[:,np.newaxis,:] - Y[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2` has `(2, 2, 2)`  dimension and `np.sum` do summation on specific dimension: which one : `axis=-1`.

```
dist_sq = np.sum((Y[:,np.newaxis,:] - Y[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)

dist_sq=
array([[0.        , 0.09266431],
       [0.09266431, 0.        ]])
```

For example :

```
(0.79410882-0.93574123)**2 + (0.38156374-0.6510161)**2  = 0.09266431387197768
```

So final solution is a square matrix that is symmetrical.

Comment: What does negative axis do?!

Comment: axis=-1 means last dimension.

Comment: It would be much nicer if such explanation could be added to the original text in that book (where the puzzle was from) along with the explaintion that axis=-1 mean the last dimension.